# Java script function to hide a <span>?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Hi i have the following code:

```
<a onclick="show_login()">Login
<span id="login" style="visibility: hidden">
<form method="post" action="login.php"> 
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" /></a>
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" />

<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
</form>
</span>
```

I want to know how to hide/show that span using the function name "show_login". How would i go about doing this?

Comment: You have some mismatched tags; the `a` tag ends inside of the `span` (and the `span` tag started in the `a` tag). You might get some unexpected behavior unless your tags are matched.

Answer (score 5):

You probably shouldn't be using a `<span>` for that, `<div>` would serve you better. And `visibility` probably isn't what you want either, [`visible: hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#visibility):

> **hidden**
>   The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout. Furthermore, descendants of the element will be visible if they have 'visibility: visible'.

And you should close your `<a>` before the login form.

You probably want to use `display: none` and `display: block`. So something like this:

```
<a onclick="toggle_login()">Login</a>
<div id="login" style="display: none">
    <form method="post" action="login.php"> 
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" /></a>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And:

```
function toggle_login() {
    var div = document.getElementById('login');
    div.style.display = div.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    return false;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6ngnU/1/

Answer (score 0):

Set the style to display: none to start with and use the jquery function show to make it appear when you want it.

http://api.jquery.com/show/